# ng build generates a previus version of my project

Tags: angular, git, build

I've been almost all day trying to get the app finished with the ng build command, i have builder the same app multiple times to copy the dist folder in my apache, but suddenly, when i just finished a new feature using ng serve, it was working on local, but when I did ng build, i dont know why is deploying an older version, where the feature i just created dont exist, I have tried so many things, like *ng build --watch*, or *ng build myprojectname*, nothing is working, always getting the same dist files with even the same filenames.

I dont know what i'm doing wrong because it is my first angular app, I tried to pull request the branch of the feature into main branch, but main branch dont detect the changes of the other branch i was working.

I don't know if the git thing matters or not, but previously I didn't need to switch to the main branch for the build to work.

Finally, clarify that in the same folder and branch in which everything works correctly when doing ng serve, when doing ng build it comes out out of date.

I'm working with angular cli 15.2

Do you think i am missing something? Thanks and sorry for the question.

Comment: - Check that you are using the correct branch.
- Check your angular.json. 
- run `ng build --clean`
- Check which environment is being used for deployment

Comment: Solved! I dont know wich was the problem, I switched to the local master branch and I setted the budget of the angular.json file to 5mb, now is deploying the updated dist.
Thank you!!